# Syntax error while running python3 manage.py runserver

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, django-manage.py, django-runserver

Im facing the below issue on my mac when I run  'python3 manage.py runserver' command

> THE HOST IS ===>SHEEKRIS-M-V6GG
> File "/Users/sheekris/DjangoDeveloperProject/django_api/gve-api/app/manage.py", line 16
> ) from exc
> ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Below are the python installation details

```
SHEEKRIS-M-V6GG:sheekris$ type -a python3
python3 is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
python3 is /usr/local/bin/python3
python3 is /usr/bin/python3

SHEEKRIS-M-V6GG: sheekris$ which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: What is the code in your file?

Comment: It seems you have syntax error at line 16